# Não parar setTimeOut quando alterar abas do navegador

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou construindo um contador com `vueJS` e notei que a contagem para quando troco o foco da aba; a principio estou utilizando a função `setTimeout`do javscript:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.time++

    this.min  = Math.floor(this.time/100/60)
    this.sec  = Math.floor(this.time/100)
    this.mSec =  this.time % 100

    this.timer() // recursividade

}, 10);
```

Se eu manter o foco na aba, ou mover a aba para outro monitor o contador funciona perfeitamente, porém se eu trocar de aba o contador é pausado automaticamente, existe uma maneira de não para o `setTimeout` ao trocar o foco da aba do navegador?

Answer (score 1):

Os navegadores mais modernos suspendem alguns códigos JavaScript, como o `setTimeout`, quando a janela não está em foco para economizar recursos de energia e processamento. Imagine se ficasse executando JavaScript quando você minimizasse seu navegador no celular.

Uma solução é criar um listener para alguns hooks. Por exemplo, quando o foco é perdido da aba, você salva o tempo e quando o foco retorna você subtrai e vê quanto tempo passou para ajustar seu timer.

Para verificar esses hooks, pode fazer uso da [API de Page Visibility, descrita no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

```
// Set the name of the hidden property and the change event for visibility
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");

// If the page is hidden, pause the video;
// if the page is shown, play the video
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document[hidden]) {
    videoElement.pause();
  } else {
    videoElement.play();
  }
}

// Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || typeof document.hidden === "undefined") {
  console.log("This demo requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
} else {
  // Handle page visibility change   
  document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

  // When the video pauses, set the title.
  // This shows the paused
  videoElement.addEventListener("pause", function(){
    document.title = 'Paused';
  }, false);

  // When the video plays, set the title.
  videoElement.addEventListener("play", function(){
    document.title = 'Playing'; 
  }, false);

}
```

> **Timeouts in inactive tabs throttled to >=1000ms**
>
> To reduce the load (and associated battery usage) from background
>   tabs, timeouts are throttled to firing no more often than once per
>   second (1000 ms) in inactive tabs.
>
> Firefox implements this behavior since version 5 (see bug 633421, the
>   1000ms constant can be tweaked through the
>   dom.min_background_timeout_value preference). Chrome implements this
>   behavior since version 11 (crbug.com/66078).
>
> Firefox for Android uses a timeout value of 15 minutes for background
>   tabs since bug 736602 in Firefox 14, and background tabs can also be
>   unloaded entirely.
>
> [retirado do Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Inactive_tabs)

Comment: meu timer e uma variável simples de incremento como posso "calcular" o tempo que a aba esteve fora de foco se o javascript vai estar "pausado"?